# Skyrim Xbox 1 door puzzle glitch

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I've tested this with multiple door puzzles and I put in the right code and i go to place the claw in to open the door and the "activate" icon won't do anything, I could click it a thousand times and it isn't working. I have all game friendly mods on and i can't figure out why the doors are broken.

Mods:

- Unofficial Skyrim patch
- Campfire
- Increased follower limit
- BIG: More killmoves
- Alternate start
- Skyrim graphic overhaul
- Enhanced blood textures
- Vivid weather
- All armor lootable and wearable
- Immersive civil war units
- Relationship dialogue overhaul
- Static Mesh Improvements
- Frostfall
- Roman Imperial armor replacement
- Kissing-Immersive lovers
- Unique magicka swords(lightsabers)

Comment: A list of your mods would be appreciated, since any one of them could potentially break your game.

Answer (score 7):

There are a few distinct possibilities for your issue.

1. Your mods, despite your claim of **game friendly**, may have indeed broken. As you've ignored that request, we can't help you there.
2. The claw puzzle is glitched. According to the [UESP Puzzles Page](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Puzzle_Totems#Bugs), this can happen in some saves. There are a variety of solutions to choose from, listed as follows:

   - Save and then immediately load that save.
   - Load either the auto-save from the entrance, or a save from before you entered.
   - Exit the location, save, and load that save.
   - "Reset" the door by selecting the right combination and try the claw, then turn each ring once and try the claw again. Do this until the correct combination re-appears and try again.
   - (PC ONLY) Type tcl into the Console to clip through the door. Reenter the code once past. Note that unlock will not work.

Try these solutions, and please, don't assume that your **game friendly** mods are not causing any problems.